# Using intent to pass spinner objects to a new activity via a button

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-studio, spinner

On the first activity I have a spinner and a button. I want to make it so that when a spinner option is chosen and then the button is clicked, a new activity is opened and the spinner option is displayed (along with additional information about it) in a TextView. In short, I'm trying to use intent to send and retrieve data, and then add additional information afterwards, which I think I would use putExtra() method.

Here I have the button directing to the second page and I am trying to store the spinner's object via intent.
`MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Selected.class);
            intent.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Here is Selected.class (second activity)
I want to retrieve the spinner info and put it into a textview.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
    }
}
```

Also, here is the spinner array named "person_array":

```
<string-array name="person_array">
    <item>Nick</item>
    <item>Isaac</item>
    <item>Sally</item>
    <item>Matt</item>
    <item>Tim</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 3):

problem in your code is that you are creating two different intent object. The former filled up with the string:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Spinner.class);
  i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
```

and you use the latter to star the Selected activity.

```
  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Selected.class));
```

You should use only one

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Selected.class);
 intent.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");    
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ah I see, and I had spinner in the second parameter when I should have put the destination/Selected.class. Edited the main post~

Comment: Don't like to double comment but, what would I do to pull up an object chosen from the spinner in a textview on this new page? It loads the blank page correctly but I would like the object to appear in a textview and then use a putExtra method to add additional information.

Comment: create a layout with your view and pass it to `setContentView` . Retrieve the `TextView` trough `findViewById` and call `setText` on the instance

Comment: Hmm this is where I am definitely lost lol. I have created a textview in the appropriate layout file (activity_selected.xml) but I don't know what to do with it in the Selected.class file. I haven't used setContentView or findViewById yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, you create an `Intent` (`i`), pointing to something that is not an Android application component (`Spinner`), put an extra on it, and then throw it away. This will not be useful.

Instead, put your extra on the `Intent` that you are using with `startActivity()`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Selected.class)
                .putExtra("new_variable_name","value"));
```